# How to add an animation in adding a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I had a button on the navigationbar.
When clicking on that I need to add a subview to the self.view.

```
DemoViewController *demoViewController1 = [[DemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    CGRect frame=demoViewController1.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -300;
     [self.view addSubview:demoViewController1.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame1 = frame;
                         frame1.origin.y = 0;
                         demoViewController1.view.frame = frame1;
                     }];
```

I was tried by setting the frame origin y of the adding view(it is of another view controller).to some negetive value and by clicking bring it to 0.but it doesnt have that drop down effect.

I need to add the view with an animation like drop down view. and when pressed again on the button need to remove also like this.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: place it at a higher y then gradually make y to 0 inside animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the view as subview with a frame that is not on the screen (e.g. negative y coordinate) and modify the frame animated:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, -200, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = myView.frame;
                     frame.origin.y = 0;
                     myView.frame = frame;
                 }];
```

And the code for removal:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = myView.frame;
                     frame.origin.y = -1 * frame.size.height;
                     myView.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [myView removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

**Edit:**

Replace your code with this:

```
DemoViewController *demoViewController1 = [[DemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    CGRect frame=demoViewController1.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -300;
    demoViewController1.view.frame = frame; // You forgot this line
     [self.view addSubview:demoViewController1.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame1 = demoViewController1.view.frame;
                         frame1.origin.y = 0;
                         demoViewController1.view.frame = frame1;
                     }];
```

Comment: is there any way in CAtransition.because the view is of another viewcontroller

Comment: If you want to add it as subview, you can do it this way just use `viewController.view` instead of `myView` (also add that `viewController` to the `currentViewController.childViewControllers`). If you have an iPad app, I recommend presenting it inside of a UIPopoverController. You can open it from your UIBarButtonItem instead of doing the animations yourself.

Comment: in removal i tried [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    animations:^{
        CGRect frame2 =[self.view viewWithTag:111].frame;
        NSLog(@"%f",frame2.origin.y);
        frame2.origin.y = -1 *frame2.origin.y;
        NSLog(@"%f",frame2.origin.y);
        [self.view viewWithTag:111].frame = frame2;
        //demoViewController1.view.alpha=0.0;
       
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       
       [[self.view viewWithTag:111] removeFromSuperview];
    }];But there is no animation in the reverse,i have also tried to set alpha 0 but not affected.can u help me?

Comment: First of all, declare a variable: `UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:111];` and use this one instead of calling `viewWithTag:` every time. When you say no animation, you mean the view doesn't disappear at all? When you added the view, did you write `demoViewController1.view.tag = 111`?

Comment: no it will defenitely disappear as for removefromsuperview,but i need to remove that view with just the opposite animation..thats not happening

Comment: I think I see the problem. You say `frame2.origin.y = -1 *frame2.origin.y;` but the `origin.y` was 0 if you used the above code, so -1 * 0 is still 0. Replace that line with `frame2.origin.y = -1 *frame2.size.height;`

Answer (score 0):

First keep ur view at bottom.
when it's clicked first time

do this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
//keep points that's in a screen
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(x,y,width,height);
}];
```

when it's clicked second time
give points below the visible screen

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
//keep points that's in a screen
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(x,y,width,height);
}];
```

Let me know if you find a better way than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.yourView setFrame:setYourInitialFrame];
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.00 animations:^{
    [self.yourView setFrame:setYourFinalFrame];
}];
```

Comment: is there any way in CAtransition.because the view is of another viewcontroller.